# Firefox inspector 'pick an element' tool shows incorect position

Tags: firefox, browser, element, web-inspector, inspector

After updating `firefox` to new version, when i choose the pick an element tool then hover the mouse over elements, the inspector blue box goes on an incorrect position.
Anyone Know how to resolve this problem ?

My current version of `firefox` is 45.0.2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is firefox bug report it to [HERE](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)